# is it possible multiline with input type as number in Android Edittext?

Tags: android-edittext

When the android edittext input type is number, is it possible to make multilines?
I have tried with the following in xml file.

android:inputType="number|textMultiLine"

But it did not work. Is it not possible to make multiline when the input type is number?

Please help me in this.
Thank you.

Comment: the trick is to add android:digits="0123456789\n". as the "\n" lets you create new lines

Comment: This seems to solve this: [Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32163224/inputtype-number-with-more-than-one-line)

Answer (score 2):

Please do this:

```
android:inputType="textMultiLine|number"
android:digits="0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9"
```

Taken from here: [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32163224/inputtype-number-with-more-than-one-line)

Answer (score 1):

I tried each and every solution for your problem.The thing is that when you try to use **android:inputType** attribute with **number** android doesnot provide **textMultiLine** feature for users.it is possible with only one attribute i.e., **android:numeric="integer"**.I know that ***it is Deprecated*** but for your problem **this is the only solution**.

I have made a sample xml file.it is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:lines="10"
        android:numeric="integer" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:maxLines="10"
        android:numeric="integer" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:maxLines="10"
        android:numeric="integer" />

</LinearLayout>
```

There are sample EditText used with explanation as follows:-

The first one describes the TextView be ***exactly*** this many lines tall by using the attribute-**android:lines="10"**.Here if you donot provide **android:gravity="top"** then any input you do will start from the **center** of the EditText.

The second one describes the TextView be ***at most*** this many lines tall by using the attribute-**android:maxLines="10"**.

I hope you will finally be happy for your problem being solved successfully.