# lock android keyboard to only show numerics

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an android app that uses an EditText with `android:inputType="number"`
when the edittext first displays the softkeyboard appears with only numerics enabled (you can still see the other keys though.
The EditText also has `android:digits="0123456789\n"` as I want the users to be able to enter multiple lines
As soon as I hit the ENTER key to create another line the numeric keys disappear.
How can I...
a). Only show a numeric keyboard (with Enter key) e.g. just 0123456789?
b). Stop the softkeyboard showing all the other keys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want a **multiline** `EditText` *and* numeric keyboard? Seems possible, but deprecated. Check out **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859005/is-it-possible-multiline-with-input-type-as-number-in-android-edittext)** answer.

**Update:**
If everything fails, try to enforce the *numeric* type every time a line break is inserted:

```
editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
```

Comment: Not sure about it being deprecated. However just by using android:digits="0123456789.\n" the "\n" lets you create multiple lines

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution
by employing 

            `android:digits="0123456789\n"

            android:inputType="phone|textMultiLine"`

I obtain the desired effect.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
editTextField.setRawInputType(Configuration.KEYBOARD_QWERTY);
```

This shows the normal key pad with the numeric version first, yet allows you to switch between them.

```
getInput.setRawInputType(Configuration.KEYBOARD_12KEY);
```