# Android Numeric EditText with multiple Lines

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have a numeric `EditText` and when I try to set multiple lines it doesn't work.

This is my code

```
      <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="phone" />
```

Java class

```
EditText editText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText);
editText.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_PHONE|InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_MULTI_LINE);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859005/is-it-possible-multiline-with-input-type-as-number-in-android-edittext in the first comment.

Comment: I agree with @shkschneider, You can not allow number/phone with multiline so multiline only allow with text.

Comment: That is not correct look at the link above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your flags are wrong. From the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputType.html):

> **TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_MULTI_LINE**
>
> Flag for TYPE_CLASS_TEXT: multiple lines of text can be entered into the field.

So `TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_MULTI_LINE` is compatible with `TYPE_CLASS_TEXT` but **not** `TYPE_CLASS_PHONE`.

I guess you just can't.

Answer (score 0):

add these lines to your editext xml

```
 android:minLines="2"
 android:maxLines="3"
```

also, don't use  `android:singleLine="false"` since it is deprecated