# inputType="number" with more than one line

Tags: android, android-layout

I have the following `EditText`:

```
<EditText
     android:id="@+id/txt1"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_gravity="center"
     android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
     android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
     android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
     android:background="@drawable/rounded_corners"
     android:hint="Txt1"
     android:inputType="number"
     android:minLines="2"
     android:text=""/>
```

where `rounded_corners` it's:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#FFFFFFFF" />

    <solid android:color="#FFFFFFFF" />

    <padding
        android:left="1dp"
        android:right="1dp"
        android:top="1dp" />

    <corners android:radius="5dp"/>

</shape>
```

**The problem** it's that I don't know how to do this `EditText` **bigger** (it just display one line) when I add **`inputType="number"`**. I mean that it could have more than one line displayed.

**What I have tried**

**1)** Change the `layout_height` to `match_parent`.

**2)** Add to the `inputType` attribute the value `textMultiLine`.

**3)** Set a fixed height with `android:height`.

**4)** As you can see in the code above, I also add `android:minLines` attribute.

**5)** I also tried setting a number of lines with `android:lines`.

None of this methods solve my problem so any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you mean the user can input new lines as he wants or just show multiline numbers under some circumstances without the user inputting new lines?

Comment: @shhp That by default have more than one line and if I type three lines, the three lines will be show.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Please add these two lines to your EditText XML file, it works:

```
android:inputType="textMultiLine|number"

android:digits="0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9"
```

Answer (score 0):

You might add the `android:singleLine` attribute and set it to `false` (*it will probably still not work though*). However, it seems rather odd to use `textMultiLine` and `number` together as the new line character is neither a number nor number related.

Also note that the `inputType` attribute is merely a *hint* for the IME and not all of them may honor the set values.

Comment: With `android:singleLine="false"` still doesn't work. And I know that `textMultiLine` and `number` sounds strange but I wanted to prove all the posibilities. I can't find the solution to this problem.

Comment: Possibly because there is no this kind of a solution. If you want multiple lines with number as the input type, catch the new line character event and add a new EditText to the layout below the current one so that this new field could be used as the next line.

Comment: It could be a workaround (so dirty in my opinion) just if you have 2 lines of numbers but imagine that you have 300 lines. Do you have to create 300 `EditText` one below the others?

Comment: Yes, you can use a RecyclerView for that. Also it looks like this is your only option. As I told you, the semantics are wrong with a multiline number type EditText.

Comment: There is one more possible solution: you provide a numpad-like layout and a normal EditText with multiline input type (note that you wouldn't set the *number* this time). This way the users can use your "keyboard" to enter text into your multiline EditText. You just have to make sure to handle the focus events properly as you wouldn't want to let the normal keyboard showing.

Comment: Don't worry about the `multiline` because it was a prove and I have been removed it some hours ago (I just put it on the question to avoid someone said to me use it) and I don't understand very well what do you mean with your solution. Can you provide an example or a link in which I can see it please?

Comment: Create an EditText which is `android:inputType="textMultiLine"`, this will be your multiline number container. Then you create a layout which contains the *number buttons*, so 0-9, delete, return (*enter*). This will act as the keyboard for your EditText. Whenever the EditText receives the focus, you should display this layout for the user in order to let them enter numbers.

Comment: I'm so grateful with the help provided but the solution of `awadesh` was easier and more clear. Just what I wanted. Thanks again!